# Set the edge layer in pyvis

Tags: python, networkx, pyvis

I would like to have thick edges (black in the image below) on top of thin edges (grey in the image below) in pyvis, is this somehow possible?

[image]

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from pyvis.network import Network

def rgb_to_hex(r, g, b):
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g, b)

G = nx.complete_graph(20)
net = Network()
net.from_nx(G)

for edge in net.edges:
    random_number = np.random.rand()*0.6 + 0.2
    edge["color"] = rgb_to_hex(int(255 * (1 - random_number)), int(255 * (1 - random_number)), int(255 * (1 - random_number)))
    edge["width"] = int(4 * random_number)

net.toggle_physics(False)
net.save_graph("test.html")
```